# NSIndexpath is shown as an DateTime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, nsindexpath

I have an `UITableView` with 2 sections

In my debug panel:

```
indexPath = (NSIndexPath)2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

[image]

This looks to me like an `DateTime` format
Xcode bug?
Any suggestions why this happens?

Comment: it is not  a dateTime format

Comment: provide the complete error message and log

Comment: Is indexPath created there? Could be pointing on a memory but not "created yet".

Comment: @vijeesh error message? log?

Comment: @Larme IIRC the debugger shows the "real type", not the "declared type" between braces. Weird.

Comment: I have cleaned, and cleaned the build folder and removed the derived data and restarted xcode. Which helped. Now the introspection gives a indexPath = (NSIndexPath) 0x7b09c560 which is a more expected result.